# Open HTTP Protocol Cisco ASA

Tags: firewall, cisco, cisco-asa

I would like to know if it's possible to open HTTP protocol (whatever the port) for one of my subnet to the outside on Cisco ASA 5510 v9.1(4) (ASDM v7.1(5)?

I guess I will have to play with service policy, but I don't know how (btw the tag "service-policy" doesn't yet exists).

For me, the Cisco ASA 5510 is a true applicative firewall, do you confirm ?
Thank you,

UPDATE:
ETL, regarding your answer can you take a look at what I'm seeing in my services ?
For me, ASA is able to handle distinction to identify tcp/udp/icmp/ospf/... but not looking into protocol tcp ? isn't it ?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your sentence. When you select to allow "tcp/http" like you did, that means that it will allow port 80. If you mean that "will the ASA make sure it is web traffic on port 80", I guess that can be done with inspection rules which is another section in your ASA configuration.

Comment: Exactly, I'm not sure all 'http' traffic is on port 80. Sometimes, websites are on port 8080, 81,... I would like to allow these port only if it's http traffic. Is it more clear ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to do so by enabling tcp/http on your firewall ACLs. And yes, it is definitely *applicative* (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/applicative)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to do application layer inspection and alter it to include other ports.

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa72/configuration/guide/conf_gd/inspect.html